# Using Filter in Google Webmasters

Tags: google-search-console

I am trying to use the Google Webmasters Filters to filter out URLs with certain words, but I am not able to get it to work.

The image link of the filter I am trying to use is below:
[image]

So when I try to filter URLs with the words SID (or other relevant words), it doesn't work. Am I using it right? How do we use this filter?

Comment: No answer on this ? I thought someone must have understood how to use this.

Comment: Have you got an adblocker enabled? Might be blocking some Google url requests.

Comment: I am not sure what happened, but it seems to be working fine now ! strange. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

[image]

When I type something into the filter box, it only shows the items that match that filter.   I don't even need to press a button or hit enter.   It adjusts the list as I type.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be working fine for me too now. I have done nothing new and am sure it was not working then. Could be some issue that Google sorted out ? Thanks anyways :)